# Error: Cannot find module 'dbconstant'

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have created a custom module whose functionality i want to export in other js modules, but while requiring the module i am getting the following error:

**`Error: Cannot find module 'dbconstant'`**

In file `login.js` i am doing following:

```
var dbConst = require('dbconstant');
```

which leads to error described above.

But when import the module using following code, it works fine:

```
var dbConst = require('/home/gaurav/mygitRepo/officemgmt/api/dbconstant');
```

**login.js reside @** `/home/gaurav/mygitRepo/officemgmt/api`

I seriously doubt that giving absolute path is way to do this, if not, how can i import module.

Please put a comment if `dbconstant` code is also needed for analyzing the issue, i will add that too if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only import modules like that if they reside in `node_modules`, which is where scripts installed with `npm` sit, otherwise you have to use a relative or absolute path.

The following should work though, as long as either dbconstant is a folder with the main export residing inside an `index.js` file or the javascript file is called `dbconstant` or `dbconstant.js`.

```
var dbConst = require('./dbconstant');
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your solution worked. but can you explain what you mean by `as long as either dbconstant is a folder with the main export residing inside an index.js file or the javascript file is called dbconstant or dbconstant.js`

Comment: If it's either of the following. `/api/dbconstant.js`, `/api/dbconstant/index.js`, `/api/dbconstant` the last one being a file.